# How to use spark for map-reduce flow to select N columns, top M rows of all csv files under a folder?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, spark-streaming, pyspark

To be concrete, say we have a folder with 10k of tab-delimited csv files with following attributes format (each csv file is about 10GB):

```
id  name    address city...
1   Matt    add1    LA...
2   Will    add2    LA...
3   Lucy    add3    SF...
...
```

And we have a lookup table based on "name" above

```
name    gender
Matt    M
Lucy    F
...
```

Now we are interested to output from top 100,000 rows of each csv file into following format:

```
id  name    gender
1   Matt    M
...
```

Can we use pyspark to efficiently handle this?

How to handle these 10k csv files in parallel?

Comment: You could probably use **wholeTextFiles** but if you have huge files and you need just first 1000 lines you can take rdd of file names and in mapper read first 1000 lines from hdfs line by line. I think that should work much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in python to exploit the 1000 first line of your files :

```
top1000 = sc.parallelize("YourFile.csv").map(lambda line : line.split("CsvSeparator")).take(1000)
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. This solves part of the problem. How to do a table lookup, and a new column ("gender" in the example) for each row?